# Excel VBA compare the system GUID with registered values on a workbook from INTERNET

Tags: excel, vba, networking, internet-connection, access-rights

I have generate a GUID string for each person who need my workbook.

Stored on `Validation.xlsb` Workbook (as database) on my computer. (Has public IP address)

Saved specified one in a `xlSheetVeryHidden1` for each workbook released to a person.

---

**How `Workbook_Open` event on destination workbooks (that I wrote), check it's GUID is valid on my VALIDATION workbook, across internet?**

---

The reference for GUID comperision requests are in a workbook on my system.
My computer has Public IP address connection.
Operation system is Windows 10.

Appreciated.

Comment: OT: I don't think this is a good approach at all, if you are sharing the workbook, I'm assuming you have sharepoint, teams or another sharing tool: why not to upload the file to a site and handle the permissions there on access read/writing?

Comment: How can compare two strings across internet  at last? (Stay on two workbooks)

Comment: Declare both your current WB and the external one and work accordingly `Set WBActual = ThisWorkbook`
    `Set WBToImport = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="http://example.com/workbook.xlsx")`

Comment: So you've given all these people access to read files from your PC over the internet (not even just a local network)?  Yikes that sounds like a bad idea?

Comment: This is friendly. The persons are not familiar about. My situation is simple with less risk. Are there any Idea for security? I need do that across internet connection. Generated GUID in host, is related with the guest system SID. Not usable for others. Gust send me GUID and SID. I related them on the host WB. I want the guest WB generate that system's SID, Send me (host WB) with the predefined GUID, Then host's WB if see correct, write on `xlSheetVeryHidden` of guest WB: **Verified!**